# Why doesn't python-click pass context between subcommands?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I'm trying to pass contexts between two subcommands with python-click. Here's an MWE:

```py
import click


@click.group(chain=True)
def cli() -> None:
    pass


@cli.command()
@click.pass_context
def fn1(cxt):
    cxt.obj = 1


@cli.command()
@click.pass_context
def fn2(cxt):
    print(f'{cxt.obj=}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

If I call this with `cli.py fn1 fn2`, I expect to get "cxt.obj=1", whereas I get "cxt.obj=None".

While trying to debug, I also noticed I can access the `cli`'s context from `fn1` and `fn2`, but not `fn1`'s context from `fn2`. I can therefore, set the object of `cli`'s context in `fn1`, and read from cli's context in `fn2`, but there must be a better way, where the `obj` is directly accessible in `fn2`'s context.

What is wrong with my mental model, why doesn't the context persist between subcommands? And, what is the best pattern to use when one needs to pass data between subcommands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context is copied from a parent to a child.  In your case `context.obj` for `cli()` which you do not expose in your example, is `None`.  The `None` is copied into the child context for `fn1()` and `fn2()`, but then in `fn1()` you change the copy to `1`.  Finally, in `fn2()` you receive a copy of the context for `cli()` in which `obj` is still `None`

So to achieve your desired result there are (at least) two options.

1. Make `context.obj` on the parent context a mutable object, and then mutate said object
2. As you indicated was possible, directly access the parent context via something like `ctx.parent.obj = 1`

An example of the first (my preferred) method:

#### Example

```py
import click, sys


@click.group(chain=True)
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx) -> None:
    ctx.obj = {}


@cli.command()
@click.pass_context
def fn1(ctx):
    ctx.obj['fn1'] = 1


@cli.command()
@click.pass_context
def fn2(ctx):
    click.echo(f'obj: {ctx.obj}')
```

#### Test Code

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
    print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
    print('-----------')
    cmd = 'fn1 fn2'
    print('> ' + cmd)
    cli(cmd.split())
```

#### Results:

```
Click Version: 8.1.3
Python Version: 3.7.8 (tags/v3.7.8:4b47a5b6ba, Jun 28 2020, 08:53:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
-----------
> fn1 fn2
obj: {'fn1': 1}
```

Comment: Great example, but the test here is not testing the right behaviour. The test chains the commands in the same execution, which actually doesn't showcase the main behaviour in a cli. 

In a cli you would manually run `fn1` and then manually run `fn2`. Passing context here is taken as passing context within one execution, but really you need to pass context across executions. eg. git status (return no files added and some changed files), git add . (adds a bunch of changed files), git status (now shows the update list of files). 

The example fails when using the above example fn1, fn2